# How can I update the data bound in this textarea using Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I defined a textarea using Vue.js like this:

```
<textarea type="textarea" v-model='myvalue'>
  {{myvalue}}
</textarea>
```

The data is defined here in a single component file (.vue file):

```
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      myvalue : ''
    }
  }
}
```

So, when I type something in the textarea `this.myvalue` gets updated.

But when I want to change the value from within JavaScript, I see no change in the UI/DOM:

```
this.myvalue = 'test'; // DOM doesn't get updated
```

How can I change the value of `myvalue` so the DOM gets automatically updated by Vue?

**Note:** I am using the textarea component of the [Framework-vue lib](http://framework7.io/vue/form-elements.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there was an error in the Vue.js component of the [Framework7-Vue plugin](http://www.framework7.io/vue) that I used. See details here in this ticket: https://github.com/nolimits4web/Framework7-Vue/issues/74

Answer (score 0):

`this.myvalue = 'test'; // DOM will get updated`

Comment: Sorry, that's actually what I meant and it didn't work :-(

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in Vue.js guide, interpolation on textareas won't work.

You HAVE TO use `v-model` :

```
<textarea v-model="myvalue"></textarea>
```

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Multiline-text

You should remove `{{myvalue}}` from within the `<textarea>` tag:

```
<textarea type="textarea" v-model='myvalue'></textarea>
```

Comment: I removed it but that didn't fix the issue :-(

Comment: Oh... Then can you provide us with the full code? Where are you using `this.myvalue = 'test';`?

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://github.com/valnub/twitvue03/blob/master/src/home.vue - You can find the textarea in line 30 and in line 93 I added `self.newTweet = "";` right above `window.f7.closeModal('.picker-new-tweet');` but that didn't work. Using Jade and Framework7 here.

Comment: I am starting to think there might be a bug in Framework7, so I opened an issue on their Github repo https://github.com/nolimits4web/Framework7-Vue/issues/74

Comment: Not used to work with Framework7 :) Are you sure you tried without ` {{newTweet}}` trailing on line 30? Also, no `self.newTweet = ""` on your code.

Comment: Yes, I tried it locally on my computer. Removed `{{newTweet}}` and added `self.newTweet = ""`. (Haven't commited the change yet because it's not working for some odd reason).